# Put module into component, angular

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components

I need put a **mdbModal** into a component, but the component does'nt have a module.ts archive, when try this movement I get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Export of name 'mdbModal' not found!
Error: Export of name 'mdbModal' not found!
```

I dont have examples in my collective project, What is the way of can import a module inside a component?

I'm relatively new on angular.

```
<div
  mdbModal
  #basicModal="mdbModal"
  class="modal right modal-scroll"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
  >
  ...
</div>
```

This is my parent module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ModalModule,
  WavesModule,
  InputsModule,
  ButtonsModule,
  CheckboxModule,
} from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

import { PrimeDetailRoutingModule } from './prime-detail-routing.module';
import { PrimeDetailComponent } from './prime-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [PrimeDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PrimeDetailRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    ModalModule,
    WavesModule,
    InputsModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
  ]
})
export class PrimeDetailModule { }
```

I dont have problems if I import the mdbModal inside a parent module, but yes if I need put it in the component in the absence of module.ts

Comment: Can you share the code of how you try to import mdbModal into your project?

Comment: we can import need module inside the module which declared the component.

Comment: @WangLiang where I should put the html tag, into the component or parent module ??

Comment: @Keimeno I put an example, after tried put the html tag into the parent module and its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my is, you can put a Component with a Module if the component its inside of the Module Father, example:

- App

  - MySite

    - Components <---
    - my-site.component.ts
    - my-site.module.ts
    - etc

You can put the new component in this directory <--- thats belong to MySite, you can use the next sentence in your cmd box to create:

```
ng generate component MySite/components/first-component --module app/MySite
```

After this, in the father module.ts you will see something like this:

```
import { FirstComponentComponent } from './components/first-component/first-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [FirstComponentComponent],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

prime.module.ts:

```
import {
  ModalModule,
  WavesModule,
  InputsModule,
  ButtonsModule,
  CheckboxModule,
} from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
…
@NgModule ({
  ...
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),],
  ...
})
```

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/pro/installation/

Comment: I need create a module.ts file into the component folder? It is possible??

Comment: No, no need create new module file

Comment: Ok, I will try quickly